# Why do my test cases keep failing?

Tags: c, testing

I wrote a few functions and I've checked multiple times to see if I wrote the formula down wrong or any defined variables, but those seem right. **THE TEST CASES WERE GIVEN BY MY INSTRUCTOR SO I ASSUME THOSE MUST BE ABLE TO WORK!** I'm not sure where or what the problem is in my code. By the way, the test cases for all previous functions up to the last one passed, it's just the last function, the estimateYield that's giving me problems.

NOTE: I've declared a lot of constant variables and some of them may seem to be unused right now, but you can ignore that.

```
#include "grove.h"
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define SOILQUALACONST 10 /* Number subtracted from both x and y in typeA. */
#define SOILQUALBCONST 10 /* Number subtracted from both x and y in typeB. */
#define SUNEXPXTERM 8   /* Number you subtract from x in exponent.*/
#define SUNEXPDIV1 10   /* First denominator term in first fraction in exp.*/
#define SUNEXPYTERM 12   /* Number you subtract from y in exponent.*/
#define SUNEXPDIV2 5   /* Second denominator term in second fraction in exp.*/
#define SUNEXPEMULT 10   /* The constant you are multiplying e^(exp.) by.*/
#define IRRIEXPONUM 10   /* The numerator in irrigation exposure function.*/
#define ESTYIELDNUM1 7   /* First term in fraction part of estimated yield.*/
#define ESTYIELDNUM2 7   /* Last term in fraction part of estimated yield.*/

double soilQuality(int x, int y) {
   double typeA, typeB, soilQual;

   typeA = 1 + (sqrt((pow(x - SOILQUALACONST, 2)) + (pow(y - SOILQUALACONST, 2))      * (1.0)));
   typeB = (1 + ((abs(x - SOILQUALBCONST) + abs(y - SOILQUALBCONST))/(2.0)));
   soilQual = (((x + y) % 2) * typeB) + ((1 - ((x + y) % 2)) * typeA);

   return soilQual;
}

double sunExposure(int x, int y) {
   double exponent, sunexp;

   exponent = (-0.5) * (((pow(x - SUNEXPXTERM, 2))/(SUNEXPDIV1)) + ((pow(y -
      SUNEXPYTERM, 2))/(SUNEXPDIV2)));
   sunexp = SUNEXPEMULT * exp(exponent);

   return sunexp;
}

double irrigationExposure(int x, int y) {
   double denominator, waterexp;

   denominator = (1 + abs(x - y)) * (1.0);
   waterexp = ((IRRIEXPONUM)/(denominator));

   return waterexp;
}

double estimateYield(int x, int y) {
   double waterexp, soilqual, sunexp, numerator, estyield;

   waterexp = irrigationExposure(x, y);
   soilqual = soilQuality(x, y);
   sunexp = sunExposure(x, y);

   numerator = ((ESTYIELDNUM1) - (abs(waterexp - ESTYIELDNUM2))) + 1;
   estyield = (soilqual) * (sunexp) * ((numerator)/(2.0));

   return estyield;
}
```

So basically, a few of the test cases for the last function keeps failing and I can't seem to figure out why. Here are the test cases implicated by my instructor:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "grove.h"
#include "checkit.h"

int main(){

   checkit_double(estimateYield(3,3), 0.023697  );
   checkit_double(estimateYield(1,19),0.067322 );
   checkit_double(estimateYield(7,8),  20.165240 );
   checkit_double(estimateYield(12,3),  0.007501);
   checkit_double(estimateYield(4,17), 2.371061);

   return(0);
}
```

And here is what I get when I run them:

```
Test passed on line 6.
Test FAILED on line 7.  estimateYield(1,19) is 0.088215, expected 0.067322.
Test passed on line 8.
Test passed on line 9.
Test FAILED on line 10.  estimateYield(4,17) is 2.766238, expected 2.371061.
```

And just in case you need it, the formula for the estimateYield is:

soilQuality(x,y) * sunExposure(x,y) * ((7-(abs(irrigationExposure(x,y) - 7)) + 1)/(2))

Comment: please clean up the code from unused or irrelevant stuff

Comment: did you try checking the results manually? btw: is this homework?

Comment: You should first check if your sub-functions return expected values (waterexp, soilqual, sunexp).

Comment: Yes. I've tested the first test case that failed manually and my teacher's solution is correct. But for some reason, my program says otherwise. :(

Comment: @Karen see Paul R answer. I've checked it and it works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
numerator = ((ESTYIELDNUM1) - (abs(waterexp - ESTYIELDNUM2))) + 1;
```

You are using the integer `abs` function with a `double` value and therefore you get a truncated `int` result. Changing this line to use `fabs` seems to fix the problem:

```
numerator = ((ESTYIELDNUM1) - (fabs(waterexp - ESTYIELDNUM2))) + 1;
```

This is a common problem when mixing integer and floating point arithmetic. I suggest you make all your constants and `int` variables `double`, and use floating point arithmetic (and `fabs()` !) throughout.

Note also that `gcc -Wall -Wconversion ...` would have caught the mistake for you:

```
$ gcc -Wall -Wconversion soil.c 
soil.c:58:48: warning: implicit conversion turns floating-point number into integer: 'double' to 'int' [-Wconversion]
   numerator = ((ESTYIELDNUM1) - (abs(waterexp - ESTYIELDNUM2))) + 1;
                                  ~~~ ~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Comment: This is correct. I've just verified locally and I get the expected results.

Comment: THANK YOU SO SO MUCH! I've been struggling to find why my tests don't work!

Comment: @Paul, it looks like you gave the output of clang :). gcc gave me: `warning: conversion to ‘int’ from ‘double’ may alter its value [-Wconversion]` while clang give me the same warning as you.

Comment: @Maxime: yes, you're absolutely right - actually I'm using Apple's clang from Xcode 5 (Apple LLVM version 5.0 (clang-500.2.76) (based on LLVM 3.3svn)) in this instance - it pretends to be gcc 4.2.1 but the error messages give it away...